# Regex how to get APT B NumberandLetter

Tags: php, regex, expression

I want to get a substring from these:

```
APT B 234 miami or APT M234 miami
```

I dont want to choose miami or whatever city, just APT (letter) (lettersandnumbers) this last block has to has always at least a number

```
(apt.[a-z0-9]{1,})
```

Could also contains  APT B 23-4 miami or APT M2-34 miami

Comment: What are you trying to match from above input?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=APT [A-Z] )[A-Z]*\d[A-Z\d]*
```

Comment: Would it not fail for this test case : APT B BC98CD89

Answer (score 0):

```
APT\s+[A-Z]\s*[A-Z0-9]*[0-9]+[A-Z0-9]*
```

Assuming all the characters that you require are upper case

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe:

```
$txt = 'APT M234 miami';
$resp = preg_match_all('/(APT\s*[a-zA-Z]*\s*[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(?=\s*)/',$txt,$result);

var_dump($result);
```